# Set Zoom and Center to show all markers - shows blue color in map element

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to center the map and fit the best zoom level to show all markers using this code

```
var searchname=document.getElementById("hidden_searchname").value;
if(trim(document.getElementById("longitude").value)!="")
{
    zoom=11; 
    lat=document.getElementById("latitude").value;
    longitude=document.getElementById("longitude").value;
}
else
{
    zoom=11;
    longitude="-88";
    lat="42";
}
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,longitude);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++)
{
    latlngbounds.extend(latlng[i]);
}
//map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(latlngbounds));
map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

But it shows me no map and console error i get is "type error c is null" . The url is  http://tinyurl.com/bp94qdy

Type Mcdonalds in the box and see.

I tweaked the code and it zooms correctly using the code below

```
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var index in markersArray) {

       var lat = markersArray[index].lat;
       var lng = markersArray[index].lng;
   //alert(markersArray[index].lng);
       var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        latlngbounds.extend(latlng2);
       }

    //map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(latlngbounds));
   map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
      map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

The map now shows blue until i hover over an address. Is this because the zoom is to far off or anything else?

Comment: You're using center: latlng in the mapOptions, meaning that latlng is a google.maps.LatLng object, but later you use it like for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) meaning that latlng is an array. One of them must be wrong.

Comment: That's a different question. StackOverflow is for *Specific* programming questions, not a chat site. latlng is defined as **latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,longitude);** so it is not an array.

Comment: Should i be getting the LatLng for each marker and putting them in an array and setting those as bound for the map for correct zooming and centering?

Comment: Yes, and also using those latlng's to .extend the LatLngBounds object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map is going to the middle of the Pacific Ocean, therefore it's blue. That's because you're not reading the latlon of the markers correctly. Instead of

```
  for (var index in markersArray) {

    var lat = markersArray[index].lat;
    var lng = markersArray[index].lng;

    var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     latlngbounds.extend(latlng2);
}
```

you should do

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < markersArray.length ; i++) {
     latlngbounds.extend(markersArray[i].getPosition());
}
```

Comment: Using your suggested code shows the same result, no change. Check the calculateCenter() function on the given url.

Comment: Sorry but your code is very disorganized and difficult to read, but I can see you're doing some strange things in there. For example, your <script> tag opens after you've closed </body> and </html><script></script> normally goes inside the <head> section of the document.

Comment: Additionally your function calculateCenter() will only execute if you drag the map because you're calling it from within the 'drag' event handler.

Comment: I have fixed the markup, thanks for pointing out. My function initialize()  also calls calculateCenter().

Comment: But when you call calculateCenter() from within initialize() your markersArray is still empty, so calculateCenter() does nothing. The order of things matters!

Comment: Thanks again for your time, finally fixed :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. :-)